# Is there a way to use Op.like as the second element in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

If I want to know if a column starts with a string "myString" with sequelize I can query it like this:

```
...
where: {
    column: { [Op.like]: `${myString}%` }
}
```

The equivalent SQL query would be: `... WHERE column LIKE {myString}%`

However, I want to know if the variable starts with the value in the column, it's the other way around. The equivalent query would be: `... WHERE {myString} LIKE concat(column, '%')`

Comment: `The equivalent query would be: ... WHERE otherColumn LIKE concat(column, '%')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where: {
    column: { [Op.contained]: `${myString}` },
}
```